# Tab autocomplete for files with spaces in it

Tags: shell, autocomplete

How do I tab autocomplete for files with spaces in it?

Comment: Please elaborate your use case. Do you want autocompletion for file _names_ with spaces in them? What shell are you using? Bash manages this by default on all the distros I've used.

Comment: What shell are you using? Post the output of `echo $0`. Are you looking to do something like `ls file na<tab>` where the file name is `file name`? If so, your shell will look for a file starting with the letters `na`. You'd need to escape the space: `ls file\ na<tab>`.

Comment: You... push Tab.

Comment: It should work with `bash` by default. If it's not working on your platform, we may need more info.

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted. The accepted answer is not obvious to an inexperience command-line user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes if you escape the space first,

e.g `ls file\ abc<tab>`

Otherwise the second `abc` here would be considered as another parameter, completion won't work then.